# When I tried to build a PCA plot I get the following error: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to build a pca plot and I wrote this program. But for some reason I get a blank graph. How can I fix this issue?

```
import pandas as pd

X = pd.read_csv('ANNCitydata.csv')
# load dataset into Pandas DataFrame
X1 = X.drop(['ID','City'], axis=1)
y = pd.read_csv('ANNCitydata.csv', usecols=["City"])
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
principalComponents = pca.fit_transform(X1)
principalDf = pd.DataFrame(data = principalComponents
             , columns = ['principal component 1', 'principal component 2'])
finalDf = pd.concat([principalDf, y[['City']]], axis = 1)
```

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1) 
ax.set_xlabel('Principal Component 1', fontsize = 15)
ax.set_ylabel('Principal Component 2', fontsize = 15)
ax.set_title('2 component PCA', fontsize = 20)
targets = ('Houston', 'St. Louis', 'Waterloo')  
colors = ('r', 'g', 'b')
```

```
for data, target, color in zip(finalDf,targets,colors):
    X1, y = data
    ax.scatter(X1, y, alpha=0.8, c=color, edgecolors='none', s=100, label=target)
ax.legend(targets)
ax.grid()
plt.show()
```

Error message that I get

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: which line produces the error?

Comment: x, y = data is the line that produces the error

Comment: how many values are in `data`? because it says you are unpacking it to 2 values (x and y), but in fact has more than that..

Comment: X1 contains (311,993) and y contains (311,1)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that. X1 cant be assinged since you just mentioned an error occured there...

Answer (score 0):

Your `finalDf` variable is a DataFrame, and one alone, and you're telling python to unpack its inner values into two, `x` and `y`. So python *expects* to see an iteration of pairs of data (much like you have a tuple with three iterables in `zip(finalDf,targets,colors)`), but it instead finds just one at a time.

You can carry out a sanity check to see what exactly lies within `data`, by

```py
print(data)
print(type(data))
```

Performing this kind of loop in a newly created DataFrame locally (Python 3.6), I find that a simple for loop just gives me column names.

```
for data in df:
    print(data)
# street
# city
# zip
# state
# beds
# baths
# sq__ft
# type
# sale_date
# price
# latitude
# longitude
```

I may be wrong, but I guess you want to get values from `x` and `y` columns, one at a time, there. For that purpose you *could* replace `finalDf` with `finalDf.itertuples()`, which would make `data` become an n-sized tuple, n being the amount of columns within `finalDf`. You'll have a named tuple, so `X1` and `y` become `data.x` and `data.y`, *supposing `x` and `y` are the names of your columns*.

```
for data, target, color in zip(finalDf.itertuples(),targets,colors):
    X1, y = data.x, data.y
    ax.scatter(X1, y, alpha=0.8, c=color, edgecolors='none', s=100, label=target)
```